# Chrome DevTools display wider than expected

Tags: html, css, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on a Front-end project and need to inspect elements (naturally). When doing that chrome's DevTools show me a page that has larger width than the view port with no apparent reason (a scroll bar appears in the bottom of the page and all).

I am working on Ubuntu 18.04 when running the project on Mac everything works fine.

NOTE: there was an issue, [Chrome Developer Tools displaying screen larger than I set in responsive mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346439/chrome-developer-tools-displaying-screen-larger-than-i-set-in-responsive-mode), that looks the same where the solution was to include the following line of code in the `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

My code includes this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate? Try this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346439/chrome-developer-tools-displaying-screen-larger-than-i-set-in-responsive-mode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Developer Tools displaying screen larger than I set in responsive mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346439/chrome-developer-tools-displaying-screen-larger-than-i-set-in-responsive-mode)

Comment: I don't think it is since the project runs seamlessly on Mac.
Also, since it contains
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">`